# Are these expressions not equal? Mathematica output is ambiguous

Tags: plotting, simplifying-expressions

The following plot indicates that the first expression equals the second. But how can I use Mathematica to show that is true:

```
Plot[(-(Log[(1 - P)/P]/Log[10])) - (Log[-(P/(-1 + P))]/Log[10]), {P, 0, 1}]
```

An attempt to simplify indicates the expressions are not equal:

```
FullSimplify[(-(Log[(1 - P)/P]/Log[10])) - (Log[-(P/(-1 + P))]/Log[10])]
```

That gives the following answer:

```
(Log[-1 + 1/P] + Log[-(P/(-1 + P))])/Log[10]
```

[image]

Comment: Add the option `Assumptions -> 0 < P < 1` to `FullSimplify` and it will tell you they are the same on that domain. Without assumptions, Mathematica will try to solve the equation for every possible complex value of `P` and the two equations are not generally equal due to branch cuts.

Comment: In addition to what Sjoerd said: Evaluating `FullSimplify[(-(Log[(1 - P)/P]/Log[10])) - (Log[-(P/(-1 + P))]/
    Log[10]), P > 1]` reveals that the expressions are _not_ equal for arbitrary real `P`. So _Mathematica_ would have lied if she had simplified `FullSimplify[(-(Log[(1 - P)/P]/Log[10])) - (Log[-(P/(-1 + P))]/Log[10])]` to `0`.

Comment: Always remember: *Mathematica* always assumes variables are complex-valued unless told otherwise. You did not tell `FullSimplify[]` what you know about `P`, so of course you get a general result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can ask Mathematica *when* this expression is zero, assuming we work on the reals:

```
Reduce[(-(Log[(1 - P)/P]/Log[10])) - (Log[-(P/(-1 + P))]/Log[10]) == 0, P, Reals]
(* 0 < P < 1 *)
```

`FullSimplify` will confirm that result.

```
FullSimplify[(-(Log[(1 - P)/P]/Log[10])) - (Log[-(P/(-1 + P))]/Log[10]), 0 < P < 1]
(* 0 *)
```